# Angular 10: Show some message if all checkboxes are selected

Tags: angular

I have a project based on Angular 10.

Actually the condition was:

1. I have given a list, where user select one option through radio button.

   *For example: user chooses **covid19** from the given list*
2. As user **covid19**. The symptoms of covid-19 will appear as i have uses `[ngSwitch]`.

**So i want display, person is having covid-19 or not on basis of his symptoms. and i have used checkboxes in symptoms.The user can also have more than two or more symptoms**

**all i want is if user *checks* one box i want to display some message like if user selects all boxes, he is having covid-19**

*i have tried with **ngSwitch**.

**problem is that if a user directly selects the 4th box...he will be showing positive for covid-19.
Is this correct way to achive this or can be done in some other way**

**All the symptoms listed are in increasing order. that means if user selects first he will be some normal issues... as he selects more from top he will be having high chance of covid-19**

**take-test.component.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid text-white bg-dark p-3">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12">Hello [<i class='bx bx-plus-medical'></i><span style="color: red; font-weight: bolder;">RAHUL SINGH</span><i class='bx bx-plus-medical'></i>]</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
      <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
      <hr class="my-4">
      <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
      <p class="lead">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    </div>



<!--Select your Disease-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <fieldset class="form-group" (change)="setvalue($event)">
      <h3 class="font-weight-bold text-danger">Choose Your Disease</h3>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label h4 text-success font-weight-bold">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="covid19">
          [&nbsp;COVID-19&nbsp;]
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios2" value="two">
         two
        </label>
      </div>
     
    </fieldset>
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" [ngSwitch]="choose">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
      <legend>Checkboxes</legend>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label" *ngSwitchCase="'covid19'">


         <!--symptom1-->
         <fieldset class="form-group"  >
         
          <div class="form-check" (change)="setvalue1($event)">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="fever" >
              Fever or chills
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check" (change)="setvalue1($event)">
            <label class="form-check-label">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="cough" >
              Cough
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" (change)="setvalue1($event)">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="short" >
              Shortness of breath or difficulty breathing
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" (change)="setvalue1($event)">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="body" >
              Muscle or body aches
            </label>
          </div>
          
        </fieldset>
         <!--end symtoms-->



        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label" *ngSwitchCase="'two'">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="">
          Option two is selected
        </label>
      </div>
     
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>





<!--final result of disease-->
<div class="container" [ngSwitch]="choose1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  *ngSwitchCase="'fever'">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1 h3 text-success">>>>>May be some Normal Fever or flu.<<<<<</h5>
        
            <small>Take precautions</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Just take one or two tabelts of paracetmol or taking some precautions</p>
          
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">You are noraml. just be in home</h5>
         
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Building a Healthy Community One Individual at a Time.</p>
 
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>









<!--final result of disease-->
<div class="container" [ngSwitch]="choose1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  *ngSwitchCase="'cough'">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1 h3 text-success">>>>>Just make yourself home qrantined and drink some tea or khadha<<<<<</h5>
        
            <small>Take precautions</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Just take one or two tabelts of paracetmol or taking some precautions</p>
          
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">You are noraml. just be in home</h5>
         
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Building a Healthy Community One Individual at a Time.</p>
 
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" [ngSwitch]="choose1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  *ngSwitchCase="'short'">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1 h3 text-danger">>>>>Must take your covid19 test. <<<<<</h5>
        
            <small>Take precautions</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Just take one or two tabelts of paracetmol or taking some precautions</p>
          
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">You are noraml. just be in home</h5>
         
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Building a Healthy Community One Individual at a Time.</p>
 
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container" [ngSwitch]="choose1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12"  *ngSwitchCase="'body'">
      <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start active">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1 h3 text-danger">>>>>You tested poitive for covid19.....be relax..... and take your medicine<<<<<</h5>
        
            <small>Take precautions</small>
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Just take one or two tabelts of paracetmol or taking some precautions</p>
          
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <h5 class="mb-1">You are noraml. just be in home</h5>
         
          </div>
          <p class="mb-1">Building a Healthy Community One Individual at a Time.</p>
 
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<br>
```

Thankyou

Comment: Create a StackBlitz demo

Comment: @KaustubhBadrike: Actually i am new to this... so please tell me what is **StackBiltz Demo**

Comment: @Nehasingh, philosophy of Angular is relationate variables in .ts with your .html. You should use [(ngModel)] or ReactiveForms, **not** a series of (change) events. After this you can easy use a condition to relationate all the variables

Comment: @Eliseo:  Actually i am new to angular...can you explain in more detail...how to achieve this????

Comment: [NgModel](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel) and [Reactive/Template driven forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#introduction-to-forms-in-angular)

Comment: @DaneBrouwer: how can this be done with forms.....didn't get your point???

Comment: @Nehasingh, read the documentation, is the basic, I add a "little example" using [(ngModel)] , but if you don't understand the basic, it's difficult the answer can help you

Comment: @Nehasingh StackBlitz is like an online playground for angular (and others). When you provide a StackBlitz link, the community members can see your code in action and test out potential solutions without having to setup locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neha, it's not difficult. Imagine you has one variable, well, really an array

```
symptom:boolean[]=[]
```

You can use in a input,e.g.

```
//cough
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="symptom[2]">
```

When you check in the .html, the variable sypmtom[2] in .ts get the value true; when you un-check in the .html, the variable symptom[2] in ts get the value false

This is called "two-binding" way and is the "philosopy" of Angular: relation the view (the .html) and the model (variables in the .ts). The good is that, you can know how many symptoms has the patien. I use a getter

```
get symptomsCount()
{
    return this.symptom.filter(x=>x).length
}
```

Then you can use a *ngIf in .html

```
<div *ngIf="symptomsCount==10">You has 10 symptoms</div>
```

Automatically, when you check 10 symptoms, the message "you has 10 symptoms" appear